# array in callback for reduce is not an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a callback that I am using like

```
return innerArray.reduce((prev, curr, i, array) => {
```

However, when I try to use the array (for me this is an array of objects) like

```
array[i-1].outerIndex
```

I get a JavaScript error that I cannot read a property of undefined, reading outerIndex. The only way I was able to get this to work is with

```
let prevObj = { ...array[i - 1] };
prevObj.outerIndex
```

Is there something that is not an array in the argument passed to the reduce callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something that is not an array in the argument passed to the reduce callback?

No. It is an array.

The error message says that `array[i-1]` is `undefined`.

This is probably when it is dealing with the first item in the array so `i` is `0` so you are trying to access `array[-1]` which is out of bounds.